# How do I use PostgreSQL to show total

Tags: sql, postgresql

1. I am trying to generate a report that shows the breakdown by department and the total number of employees that work for the dept and shows the total.

I tried out the below code, but am having errors

```
SELECT DISTINCT department FROM employees
UNION
SELECT department FROM departments;
SELECT COUNT(division) FROM departments
```

Comment: Please show both sample input data and expected outcome as tables.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: 1. "breakdown by department" - I do not know what this means. 2. "and shows the total" I do not know what this means

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *breakdown by department* (assuming that is count of employees in each department) by using the aggregate`count(*)` function. With that in hand use the window version of `sum(...)` function to get *shows the total* (assuming that means total employees). So (demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6a633336cabfb94acc2eadb4df8f720c))

```
select d.name             "Department" 
     , de.cnt             "Employees" 
     , sum(de.cnt) over() "Total Employees"
  from departments d 
  join ( select dept_id
              , count(*) cnt 
           from employees 
          group by dept_id 
       ) de 
     on (de.dept_id = d.dept_id)
  order by d.name;
```

References:

- [Aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) functions.
- [Window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-window.html) functions.

Answer (score 0):

After thorough research here is the answer to my earlier question

```
SELECT      department, 
            COUNT(*) 
FROM        employees
GROUP BY    department
UNION ALL
SELECT      'TOTAL', 
            COUNT(*) 
FROM        employees;
ORDER BY    department;
```